# Deploying ruby on rails on heroku cedar error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, heroku

I seem to have real trouble while deploying, I am not very much sure about the error and what has triggered it. Everything seems to be working in local using production mode as well. Please help me understand this error and deploy my app.

Now, I removed .git folder and created a new cedar app and then tried it again but as usual have some errors. But, this time the error looks different. My gem file and recent heroku log are as below;

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
group :test, :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'spork'
  gem 'annotate', :git => "https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models.git"
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'thin'
end
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'haml'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'heroku'
```

**Recent log**

```
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:38:in `receive_data'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 128ms
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:29:in `determine_template'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:61:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:80:in `block in pre_process'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:67:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:86:in `start'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `pre_process'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.
rb:18:in `process_action'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.3/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:594:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/connection.rb:78:in `catch'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor
/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.2/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.3.1/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:61:in `start'
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /] miss
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /favicon.ico] miss, store
2012-04-18T13:59:38+00:00 heroku[router]: GET k6skrd.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=0
2012-04-18T14:01:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to bouncing
2012-04-18T14:01:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from bouncing to created
2012-04-18T14:01:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-04-18T14:01:51+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGTERM
2012-04-18T14:01:57+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e production -p 13819`
2012-04-18T14:01:59+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-04-18T14:01:59+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/01/04/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:5)
2012-04-18T14:02:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> Process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2012-04-18T14:02:01+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2012-04-18T14:02:03+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2012-04-18T14:02:03+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
2012-04-18T14:02:03+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2012-04-18T14:02:03+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:13819, CTRL+C to stop
2012-04-18T14:02:04+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Your help will be much appreciated. Thankyou in advance for any  help you would offer.

Comment: are you sure you posted the whole thing? I cannot see exception name that is rooting this stack trace.

Comment: I have edited the logs to list the all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm i just went to your site and it is down, but got a weird 404 page. check the logs and see now. also, try restarting. it sounds dumb, but who knows. Maybe your Thin setup is wrong too?

Comment: It seems like Thin setup is wrong but how do I setup thin since I am using the default setting and no proc file has been defined at this moment.

Comment: If you don't have a Procfile, Heroku generates a web process for you which is defined as `web: bundle exec thin start -e $RAILS_ENV -p $PORT` documented [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support) (assuming you're using the thin gem)

Answer (score 1):

test to remove the gem 'thin' from Gemfile

Comment: I tried removing gem 'thin' from the Gemfile and removed Procfile and tried it but it does not seem to work.